# How to combine divs in same parent with variable className?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to combine *item* divs in the same parent (under *Flute, Piccolo...*), but these classnames are variable. I tried many ways but not succeed.

https://jsfiddle.net/3hm7ngk7/1/

```
<div class="score">
      <div class="Flute">
        <div class="item">item 1</div>
        <div class="item">item 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="Piccolo">
        <div class="item">item 3</div>
        <div class="item">item 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="Flute">
        <div class="item">item 5</div>
        <div class="item">item 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="Piccolo">
        <div class="item">item 7</div>
        <div class="item">item 8</div>
      </div>
      <div class="Clarinet_in_Bb">
        <div class="item">item 9</div>
        <div class="item">item 10</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Should look

```
<div class="score">
 <div class="Flute">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
    <div class="item">item 5</div>
    <div class="item">item 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Piccolo">
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
    <div class="item">item 4</div>
    <div class="item">item 7</div>
    <div class="item">item 8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Clarinet in Bb">
    <div class="item">item 9</div>
    <div class="item">item 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: it is working. what's your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working but it is not dynamic, I updated using an each function to go through all direct child of class `score`, dynamically combine classes with the same name.

`$('.score').children('div').each` will literate through each child of `.score`

Inside is basically the same as you have

```js
$('.score').children('div').each(function(i, obj) {
  let rows = $('.' + obj.className);
  rows.first().append(rows.not(':first', this).children())
  rows.not(':first').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="score">
  <div class="Flute">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Piccolo">
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
    <div class="item">item 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Flute">
    <div class="item">item 5</div>
    <div class="item">item 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Piccolo">
    <div class="item">item 7</div>
    <div class="item">item 8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Clarinet in Bb">
    <div class="item">item 9</div>
    <div class="item">item 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thhaaaaank you :)

Comment: @peterh updated, the idea is simple, get all direct child of .score then loop through, for each class that are not first in the DOM flow append its children to first() of each class.

Comment: @DominikSvoboda if this answers your question please mark it as 'answered'